# Longtable captions and labels at each break

Tags: captions, longtable

Is there a way to caption (with diffrent numbering) and label (for cross-referencing) at each break of a longtable?

Comment: The normal usage  takes the table caption, adding something like `(continued)`. Why do you want to increase the table counter?

Comment: @Bernard, I need to refer to a certain portion of the table which contains certain data, and I want the caption label to represent this data.

Comment: Why not  refer to the table with a secondary reference to the page containing this portion?

Comment: if you are forcing the break with `\newpage` then you can put a caption in the rows after the break, at automatic page breaks not easily possible

Comment: @David, I am not forcing breaks, However, I am using the "*" option placed after certain rows (i.e \\\*) to indicate that breakpoints are not to occur at such places, can I place captions after such indicator (\\\*)??

Comment: @David, it would be great if you may provide an example!!

Comment: you can place `\caption` on any longtable row.